# Why Node js tcp server not detecting disconnected client

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I am trying to communicate server-client communication using TCP-IP in node js

Below is my server side code and I have a GSM device which acts as a client.When GSM device connects to the server I get the message that device is connected! but when I cut off the power supply of GSM device then the server should recognize that device is disconnected but no any message displays on screen even if I have code for the disconnect event.

server code

```
// Load the TCP Library
net = require('net');

// Keep track of the chat clients
var clients = [];

// Start a TCP Server
net.createServer(function (socket) {

// Identify this client
socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort 

 // Put this new client in the list
 clients.push(socket);

 // Send a nice welcome message and announce
 socket.write("Welcome " + socket.name + "\n");
 broadcast(socket.name + " Device is connected!\n", socket);

 // Handle incoming messages from clients.
 socket.on('data', function (data) {
 broadcast(socket.name + "> " + data, socket);
 });

 // Remove the client from the list when it leaves
 socket.on('end', function () {
 clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
 broadcast(socket.name + " Device left.\n");
 });

 // Send a message to all clients
 function broadcast(message, sender) {
 clients.forEach(function (client) {
  // Don't want to send it to sender
  if (client === sender) return;
  client.write(message);
  });
  // Log it to the server output too
  process.stdout.write(message)
  }

  }).listen(5000);

  // Put a friendly message on the terminal of the server.
  console.log("Chat server running at port 5000\n");
```

Comment: TCP is remarkably robust, in that it will wait for a long time (hours, usually) before declaring a connection to be dead. You need to implement some sort of ping/pong-type protocol where the server tries to periodically send a message to the client to see if the connection is still active. There's only [`socket.setKeepAlive`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setkeepalive_enable_initialdelay), but it's up to the OS to determine after how long a connection is considered dead (again, this may be hours).

Comment: @robertklep same issue I used `socket.setKeepAlive(true, 60000); //1 min = 60000 milliseconds.` it detects that client is disconnected but throws exception`Exception has occurred: Error
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:568:26)` also how to find who was disconnected in multi client connection

Comment: @robertklep yes I am also getting the same problem if I use `socket.setKeepAlive`

Comment: @Valar_Dohaeris like I said, it's up to the OS to determine after what time it will consider a connection to be dead, even using keep-alive packets. For Linux, there are some `sysctl` values that determine this.

Comment: @R.zeiwald sounds like you don't add an `error` handler to your sockets.

Comment: @robertklep but can `socket.setKeepAlive` identify which client is disconnected?

Comment: @R.zeiwald it's set on a particular `socket`, which represents the client, so yes. Provided that you add an error handler to that socket.

Comment: @Valar_Dohaeris I will post you answer after I understand error handler

Comment: @robertklep I used `socket.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log('exception', error);
    });` to handle error but how do I get which client is disconnected please can you explain more how to get client name after disconnect

Comment: @R.zeiwald the `socket` variable represents the client. There is no "client name" in TCP. Are you talking about `socket.io` perhaps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148905/discussion-between-r-zeiwald-and-robertklep).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Load the TCP Library
net = require('net');

// Keep track of the chat clients
var clients = [];

// Start a TCP Server
net.createServer(function(socket) {
try {
    socket.setKeepAlive(true, 600); //1 min = 60000 milliseconds.
} catch (exception) {
    console.log('exception', exception);
}
socket.on('error', onError.bind({}, socket));

function onError(socket) {

    //console.log('Socket error!', socket);
    console.log('name', socket.name);


}
// Identify this client
socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort

// Put this new client in the list
clients.push(socket);

// Send a nice welcome message and announce
socket.write("Welcome " + socket.name + "\n");
broadcast(socket.name + " joined\n", socket);

// Handle incoming messages from clients.
socket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    broadcast(socket.name + "> " + data, socket);
});

// Remove the client from the list when it leaves
socket.on('end', function() {
    clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
    broadcast(socket.name + " left .\n");
});

// Send a message to all clients
function broadcast(message, sender) {
    clients.forEach(function(client) {
        // Don't want to send it to sender
        if (client === sender) return;
        client.write(message);
    });
    // Log it to the server output too
    process.stdout.write(message)
   }

}).listen(8003);

 // Put a friendly message on the terminal of the server.
 console.log("Chat server running at port 8003\n");
```